# Hibernate 6 migration - Sequence ID generation

Tags: hibernate

I have a base entity. I have a sequence per entity strategy.  Increment size is 100.
As per documentation in hibernate 6,  default strategy is sequence per entity.
But i couldn't find a way to set default increment size to 100.

How i can migrate the code below to work with hibernate 6.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@Audited
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "optimized-sequence")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "optimized-sequence",
        strategy = "enhanced-sequence",
        parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.CONFIG_PREFER_SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY, value = "true"),
            @Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "100")})
    private Long id;
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I have investigated the source code and found this magic trick :)
Add parameter `@Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.CONFIG_SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY_SUFFIX, value = "_SEQ")`, ie

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "optimized-sequence")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "optimized-sequence",
    strategy = "enhanced-sequence",
    parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.CONFIG_SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY_SUFFIX, value = "_SEQ"),
        @Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "100")})
private Long id;
```

It will do the trick. You will have both: sequence per entity and your custom generator settings.

**This is a detailed explanation.**
It seems that Hibernate 6 has an issue with this case.
Initial value and other configuration parameters cannot be set either, if you want to keep SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY strategy.

According to documentation

1. SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY strategy is now a default strategy, so they removed `@Parameter (name = "prefer_sequence_per_entity", value = "true")` from `SequenceStyleGenerator`.
   And you no longer can do this

   ```
    @GenericGenerator (name = "optimized_sequence_per_entity", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator", parameters = {
        @Parameter (name = "prefer_sequence_per_entity", value = "true"), 
        @Parameter (name = "initial_value", value = "10000"),
        @Parameter (name = "increment_size", value = "100")
   ```

Only this

```
    @GenericGenerator (name = "my_generic_generator", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator", parameters = {
        @Parameter (name = "initial_value", value = "10000"),
        @Parameter (name = "increment_size", value = "10")
```

2. SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY strategy is a default, until you specify a sequence name within `@GeneratedValue`. And you can do it by setting

   @GeneratedValue(generator = "my_generic_generator")
   or @GeneratedValue(generator = "any_string_I_like")

Here generator does not have to be a real generator name, it can be any string, but once you specify something here, **SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY strategy gets effectively cancelled, because generator name is now used as sequence name** and rule `<entity name> + _seq` is not applied.

So we cannot specify SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY strategy on generator level, and we cannot specify allocation_size (and other parameters) on @GeneratedValue level. In order to do this, we have to create generator (without specifying SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY strategy) and mention it in @GeneratedValue. But once we do it, SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY strategy is cancelled.

It looks like the only possibility now, if you want to keep using Hibernate 6 and not switch back to 5 until bug is fixed, is to create a custom generator and use the new @IdGeneratorType annotation.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators

Or there is some magic trick to do it, which is not documented and cannot be easily guessed. But it seems to me that it is just the case they did not consider, when you need all 3 requirements:

- Id generation set up on a BaseEntity, annotated with @MappedSuperclass
- SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY strategy
- Generator usage for setting up some paramenters, like increment_size

Maybe, Hibernate creators can help?

Comment: Works great! It would be a great idea for the documentation to be clarified

Comment: Thank you :) I think so too, maybe, I will create a request

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not sure why this does not work for you, but one possibility is that the sequence name `optimized-sequence` is not unique, and so you're picking up a different config for the generator. See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16520.
2. Don't use `@GenericGenerator` for this; use the JPA-standard `@SequenceGenerator` instead.

Comment: Please, see my answer above. @SequenceGenerator does not work as well. It seems that it is an issue with the new version.